# How to compare ends of strings in C?

Tags: c, string

I want to make sure my string ends with ".foo".  I am using C, a language I am not totally familiar with.  The best way I have found to do it is below.  Any C gurus want to make sure I'm doing this elegantly and wisely?

```
int EndsWithFoo(char *str)
{
    if(strlen(str) >= strlen(".foo"))
    {
        if(!strcmp(str + strlen(str) - strlen(".foo"), ".foo"))
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 25 answers, only 4 or 5 without problems.

Answer (score 75):

Don't call strlen more than once per string.

```
int EndsWith(const char *str, const char *suffix)
{
    if (!str || !suffix)
        return 0;
    size_t lenstr = strlen(str);
    size_t lensuffix = strlen(suffix);
    if (lensuffix >  lenstr)
        return 0;
    return strncmp(str + lenstr - lensuffix, suffix, lensuffix) == 0;
}

int EndsWithFoo(const char *str) { return EndsWith(str, ".foo"); }
```

EDIT: added NULL check for the pedantic.  For the ultra pedantic, debate whether it should return non-zero if both str and suffix are both NULL.

Comment: In this case, you can get away with using strcmp() instead of strncmp() (or even memcmp()), since we know exactly how many characters are left in both strings at that point, although the speed difference will hardly be noticeable.

Comment: any call to strlen vanishes from the assembly anyway as soon as you turn on optimizations, so that's probably a case of premature optimization (although C strings are yucky enough to make one think about such issues)

Comment: @Johannes: How can this be, for strings other than compile-time-known string literals? Certainly you can inline the strlen code, but at some level you still need to find the length of the string. For const string literals, the compiler knows how long it is, but this is not true in general. Thoughts?

Comment: when !str && !suffix, wouldn't it make more sense to return 1?

Comment: @MattJ: a bit late..., but I presume adam meant that the compiler will remove all invocations but the first one for each string because they are not changed. you are of course correct that not **all** of them can be optimized away.

Answer (score 19):

```
int EndsWithFoo(char *string)
{
  string = strrchr(string, '.');

  if (string != NULL)
    return strcmp(string, ".foo");

  return -1;
}
```

Will return 0 if ending with `".foo"`.

Comment: *humble bow* you're very kind :-)

Comment: Return values should be reversed, since zero is false and non-zero is true, and the name of the function indicates Boolean return.

Comment: @dreamlax -> yes, this is true

Comment: @Squirrel `strcmp` checks for the null terminator in both strings. If one string is shorter than the other, it will return non-zero. It won't overread.

Comment: Using variable "string" does not look as a good idea to me because can clash with std::string in c++. Unsure how well compiler can do it but it is I also would recommend using const char *. So it will be
int EndsWithFoo(const char *s1 )
{
  const char * s2 = strrchr(s1, '.');
.... and now everything with s2 further.

Comment: The name `EndsWithFoo()` suggests a non zero return value if the string does end with `".foo"`: your convention is confusing.

Answer (score 10):

I don't have access to a compiler right now, so could someone tell me if this works?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int EndsWithFoo(const char* s);

int
main(void)
{
  printf("%d\n", EndsWithFoo("whatever.foo"));

  return 0;
}

int EndsWithFoo(const char* s)
{
  int ret = 0;

  if (s != NULL)
  {
    size_t size = strlen(s);

    if (size >= 4 &&
        s[size-4] == '.' &&
        s[size-3] == 'f' &&
        s[size-2] == 'o' &&
        s[size-1] == 'o')
    {
      ret = 1;
    }
  }

  return ret;
}
```

Anyway, be sure to qualify the parameter as `const`, it tells everyone (including the compiler) that you don't intend to modify the string.

Comment: +1 most optimized. I prefer such a version when 'foo' doesn't change!

Comment: Just a tip: If you have an internet connection, you have a C compiler available at codepad.org

Comment: Murphy's Law says that ".foo" will change and at the most inopportune moment.

Comment: It's not "most optimized" as you read over the .foo part twice - once for strlen, once for comparison. Good and practical, though. +1

Comment: I'm pretty sure a standard version with a loop and const char * would optimize to something like this with -O3 anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a general solution returning the same values as Pythons str.endswith(), using memcmp(). Not checking str / suffix for NULL is intended, other libc str functions don't check for NULL also:

```
int ends_with(const char *str, const char *suffix) {
  size_t str_len = strlen(str);
  size_t suffix_len = strlen(suffix);

  return (str_len >= suffix_len) &&
         (!memcmp(str + str_len - suffix_len, suffix, suffix_len));
}
```

Test C:

```
printf("%i\n", ends_with("", ""));
printf("%i\n", ends_with("", "foo"));
printf("%i\n", ends_with("foo", ""));
printf("%i\n", ends_with("foo", "foo"));
printf("%i\n", ends_with("foo", "foobar"));
printf("%i\n", ends_with("foo", "barfoo"));
printf("%i\n", ends_with("foobar", "foo"));
printf("%i\n", ends_with("barfoo", "foo"));
printf("%i\n", ends_with("foobarfoo", "foo"));
```

Result C:

```
1
0
1
1
0
0
0
1
1
```

Test Python:

```
print("".endswith(""))
print("".endswith("foo"))
print("foo".endswith(""))
print("foo".endswith("foo"))
print("foo".endswith("foobar"))
print("foo".endswith("barfoo"))
print("foobar".endswith("foo"))
print("barfoo".endswith("foo"))
print("foobarfoo".endswith("foo"))
```

Result Python:

```
True
False
True
True
False
False
False
True
True
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can change the signature of your function, then try changing it to

```
int EndsWith(char const * str, char const * suffix, int lenstr, int lensuf);
```

This will result in a safer, more reusable and more efficient code:

1. The added const qualifiers will make sure you don't mistakenly alter the input strings.  This function is a predicate, so I assume it is never meant to have side-effects.
2. The suffix to compare against is passed in as a parameter, so you can save this function for later reuse with other suffixes.
3. This signature will give you the opportunity to pass the lengths of the strings in if you already know them.  We call this [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

We can define the function like so:

```
int EndsWith(char const * str, char const * suffix, int lenstr, int lensuf)
{
    if( ! str && ! suffix ) return 1;
    if( ! str || ! suffix ) return 0;
    if( lenstr < 0 ) lenstr = strlen(str);
    if( lensuf < 0 ) lensuf = strlen(suffix);
    return strcmp(str + lenstr - lensuf, suffix) == 0;
}
```

The obvious counter-argument for the extra parameters is that they imply more noise in the code, or a less expressive code.

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior if `lenstr < lensuf`, whether as argument values or as computed with `strlen()`. Another counter-argument is `int` has a smaller positive range than `size_t`.

Answer (score 2):

The `strlen(".foo")`s are not required. If you really wanted to have it flexible you could use `sizeof ".foo" - 1` -- a compile time constant.

Also, a null string check would be good.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't sizeof(".foo") 5, but strlen(".foo") 4?  I thought strlen was easier to read, since I'm dealing with string lengths here.  And the compiler should optimize it away to a constant...

How's the rest of the function look?

Comment: Specifically, it's not necessary because we already know how long ".foo" is.

Comment: Isn't ".foo" a const char *?  Even if counted as an array, it has five chars, since in array form it does have the terminating '\0'.

Comment: @JoeF: Right. My bad. But your function looks good to me otherwise except for a null check.

Comment: strlen used on string literals is usually optimised away anyway.

Comment: @dirkgently: What's this about NULL? I was saying that performing strlen(".foo") is optimised into a constant size_t equal to 4 using any decent compiler, since the length of the string is known at compile time. This can be verified with objdump.

Comment: @dreamlax: I mixed up another posting with this comment of yours. Taken the comment out. (I was just referring to input validation for the non-literal string argument.)

Answer (score 2):

Tested code, includes the test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int ends_with_foo(const char *str)
{
    char *dot = strrchr(str, '.');

    if (NULL == dot) return 0;
    return strcmp(dot, ".foo") == 0;
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
    char *test[] = { "something", "anotherthing.foo" };
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(test) / sizeof(char *); i++) {
        printf("'%s' ends %sin '.foo'\n",
               test[i],
               ends_with_foo(test[i]) ? "" : "not ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Snap!  Although I don't bother comparing the strcmp() result - just return it directly.

Comment: you are assuming that there is not other '.' in the input string.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference.  The strcmp() will only return 0 if there are two identical strings (e.g. the length must be the same).  The compare will finish early if the strings differ in length.

Comment: @Blank Xavier: The version in the question returns 1 if it ends in ".foo". Just returning the result of strcmp() would return 0 on success.

Comment: @Naveen: strrchr() returns the last occurrence of the searched character.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't too worried about getting the exact same return value - as long as the return value is defined, so you know what it will do, that's fine.

Comment: This solution works for a hard coded `".foo"` extension, but the method would fail if the extension contains multiple `.` such as `".tar.gz"`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the most efficient(for a computer) answer you will find here.

```
int endsWith(const char *string,const char *tail)
{

    const char *s1;

    const char *s2;

    if (!*tail)
        return 1;
    if (!*string)
        return 0;
    for (s1 = string; *s1; ++s1);
    for (s2 = tail; *s2; ++s2);
    if (s1 - string < s2 - tail)
        return 0;
    for (--s1, --s2; *s1 == *s2 && s2 >= tail; --s1, --s2);
    if (s2 < tail)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid `s2 >= tail` invokes undefined behavior if `s2` is decremented before the beginning of `tail`, and so does `if (s2 < tail)`. You should write `while (*--s1 == *--s2) { if (s2 == tail) return 1; } return 0;`

Comment: @chqrlie thinking in your comment, I just changed the order of the comparison: `s2 >= tail && *s1 == *s2;` Thanks!

Comment: @DanielDeLeón: I'm afraid your fix is invalid: in case of a match, you are going to dereference `*s2` with `s2 = tail - 1` which has undefined behavior. Furthermore, even `s2 < tail` has undefined behavior if `s2` has been decremented before the beginning of `tail`. Why not use my suggestion: `while (*--s1 == *--s2) { if (s2 == tail) return 1; } return 0;` ?

Comment: Thank you @chqrlie! You play it safe, and is the best strategy with C. I really appreciate your attention to details. Now I use your suggestion and works really fine!

Comment: @DanielDeLeón: actually my comment was referring to the current code in the question. You fix is invalid because decrementing `s2` past the beginning of `tail` has undefined behavior. `s2 >= tail` is meaningless in this case anyway.  Here is a pathological example: on MS/DOS and or 16-bit Windows, using large model or far pointers, if `tail` has an offset of `0x0000`, `tail - 1` would have an offset of `0xFFFF` and the same segment, causing `tail - 1 >= tail` to evaluate to true.

Answer (score 2):

> *Any C gurus want to make sure I'm doing this elegantly and wisely?*

Your solution works **correctly** as long as the argument is a valid null terminated string. This is the **most important** and in this regard, you are doing this **wisely**. More complicated solutions posted as answers do not meet this goal.

The compiler will inline `strlen(".foo")` and should be able to determine that both instances of `strlen(str)` return the same value, hence generate a single call as [(**clang** and **gcc** do)](https://godbolt.org/z/cdhfncq5b).

Yet it would be more *elegant* IMHO to compute the lengths once and use `memcmp()` instead of `strcmp()` which needs more work and is not inlined. You should also define `str` as a `const char *` to achieve `const` correctness and prevent warnings when calling your function with constant strings or string literals.

Testing for a specific `".foo"` suffix is a special case of a more general problem: testing that a string is a suffix of another string.

Here is a simple and efficient solution:

```
#include <string.h>

int strEndsWith(const char *s, const char *suff) {
    size_t slen = strlen(s);
    size_t sufflen = strlen(suff);

    return slen >= sufflen && !memcmp(s + slen - sufflen, suff, sufflen);
}

int strEndsWithFoo(const char *s) {
    return strEndsWith(s, ".foo");
}
```

The code is very simple and generic, yet modern compilers will inline `strEndsWithFoo` very efficiently. As can be verified on [GodBolt's compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/WTb8h79fs), **clang 12.0.0** computes the length of `".foo"` at compile time and inlines `memcmp()` as a single `cmp` instruction, generating just 12 x86_64 instructions:

```x86asm
strEndsWithFoo:                            # @strEndsWithFoo
        pushq   %rbx
        movq    %rdi, %rbx
        callq   strlen
        movq    %rax, %rcx
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        cmpq    $4, %rcx
        jb      .LBB1_2
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        cmpl    $1869571630, -4(%rbx,%rcx)      # imm = 0x6F6F662E
        sete    %al
.LBB1_2:
        popq    %rbx
        retq
```

**gcc 11.2** generates very similar code, also 12 instructions:

```x86asm
strEndsWithFoo:
        pushq   %rbx
        movq    %rdi, %rbx
        call    strlen
        xorl    %r8d, %r8d
        cmpq    $3, %rax
        jbe     .L7
        xorl    %r8d, %r8d
        cmpl    $1869571630, -4(%rbx,%rax)
        sete    %r8b
.L7:
        movl    %r8d, %eax
        popq    %rbx
        ret
```

Intel's ICC compiler generates a long and complex set of SIMD instructions, much more difficult to follow and possibly less efficient even on Intel processors. The performance depends heavily on the efficiency of the `strlen()` library function, so benchmarks should include various distributions of string lengths.

There is no absolute answer to *what if the most efficient solution?* but simplicity does not preclude efficiency, and simple straightforward code is easier to validate. When it combines simplicity, correctness and efficiency, *elegance* is achieved.

Quoting [Brian Kernighan](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Brian_Kernighan):

- Controlling complexity is the essence of computer programming.
  *Software Tools (1976)*, p. 319 (with P. J. Plauger).
- Everyone knows that debugging is twice as hard as writing a program in the first place. So if you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?
  *"The Elements of Programming Style"*, 2nd edition, chapter 2.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I'm a little late to the party.
Couldn't you do something with some simple pointer math?

```
char* str = "hello.foo"; //this would be string given

int x = 4; //.foo has 4 characters

int n = strlen(str)- x; //where x is equal to suffix length

char* test = &str[n]; //do some pointer math to find the last characters

if(strcmp(test, ".foo") == 0){
    //do some stuff
}// end if
```

Character pointers work by pointing to the first character in their array. So when you do this you set test's first character as the '.' in '.foo' (if that's what it contains). That's also why you don't need to allocate memory for it since it is just pointing at the already existing array of characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

int string_has_suffix(const char *str, const char *suf)
{
    assert(str && suf);

    const char *a = str + strlen(str);
    const char *b = suf + strlen(suf);

    while (a != str && b != suf) {
        if (*--a != *--b) break;
    }
    return b == suf && *a == *b;
}

// Test Unit
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    assert( string_has_suffix("", ""));
    assert(!string_has_suffix("", "a"));
    assert( string_has_suffix("a", ""));
    assert( string_has_suffix("a", "a"));
    assert(!string_has_suffix("a", "b"));
    assert(!string_has_suffix("a", "ba"));
    assert( string_has_suffix("abc", "abc"));
    assert(!string_has_suffix("abc", "eeabc"));
    assert(!string_has_suffix("abc", "xbc"));
    assert(!string_has_suffix("abc", "axc"));
    assert(!string_has_suffix("abcdef", "abcxef"));
    assert(!string_has_suffix("abcdef", "abxxef"));
    assert( string_has_suffix("b.a", ""));
    assert( string_has_suffix("b.a", "a"));
    assert( string_has_suffix("b.a", ".a"));
    assert( string_has_suffix("b.a", "b.a"));
    assert(!string_has_suffix("b.a", "x"));
    assert( string_has_suffix("abc.foo.bar", ""));
    assert( string_has_suffix("abc.foo.bar", "r"));
    assert( string_has_suffix("abc.foo.bar", "ar"));
    assert( string_has_suffix("abc.foo.bar", "bar"));
    assert(!string_has_suffix("abc.foo.bar", "xar"));
    assert( string_has_suffix("abc.foo.bar", ".bar"));
    assert( string_has_suffix("abc.foo.bar", "foo.bar"));
    assert(!string_has_suffix("abc.foo.bar", "xoo.bar"));
    assert(!string_has_suffix("abc.foo.bar", "foo.ba"));
    assert( string_has_suffix("abc.foo.bar", ".foo.bar"));
    assert( string_has_suffix("abc.foo.bar", "c.foo.bar"));
    assert( string_has_suffix("abc.foo.bar", "abc.foo.bar"));
    assert(!string_has_suffix("abc.foo.bar", "xabc.foo.bar"));
    assert(!string_has_suffix("abc.foo.bar", "ac.foo.bar"));
    assert( string_has_suffix("abc.foo.foo", ".foo"));
    assert( string_has_suffix("abc.foo.foo", ".foo.foo"));
    assert( string_has_suffix("abcdefgh", ""));
    assert(!string_has_suffix("abcdefgh", " "));
    assert( string_has_suffix("abcdefgh", "h"));
    assert( string_has_suffix("abcdefgh", "gh"));
    assert( string_has_suffix("abcdefgh", "fgh"));
    assert(!string_has_suffix("abcdefgh", "agh"));
    assert( string_has_suffix("abcdefgh", "abcdefgh"));

    return 0;
}

// $ gcc -Wall string_has_suffix.c && ./a.out
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...

```
bool endswith (const char *str, const char *tail)
{
  const char *foo = strrstr (str, tail);
  if (foo)
  {
     const int strlength = strlen (str);
     const int taillength = strlen (tail);
     return foo == (str + strlength - taillength);
  }
  return false;
}

endswith (str, ".foo");
```

By the way, the solution in the original question looks fine other than the repeated `strlen` calls.

Comment: strrstr() is non standard and does not exist, at least on glibc 2.15

Comment: Simpler with the same approach: `return foo && strlen(foo) == strlen(tail);`

Answer (score 0):

If there's always something beyond the dot, we could indulge in some pointer arithmetic:

```
int EndsWithFoo (char *str)
{
   int iRetVal = 0;
   char * pchDot = strrchr (str, '.');

   if (pchDot)
   {
      if (strcmp (pchDot+1, "foo") == 0)
      {
         iRetVal = 1;
      }
   }
   return iRetVal;
}
```

Of course you would probably want to add a little strlen there to check there *is* something beyond the dot :-)

NB - I didn't run this to check it, but it looks OK to me.

Comment: This solution does not work if the extension contains multiple `.`, such as `".tar.gz"`.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to use my version:

```
bool endsWith(const char *filename, const char *ext) {
    const uint len = strlen(filename);
    const uint extLen = strlen(ext);
    if (len < extLen) {
        return false;
    }
    for (uint index  = 1; index <= extLen; index++) {
        if (filename[len - index] != ext[extLen - index]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You should include `<string.h>` and use `size_t` instead of `uint`

Answer (score 0):

I always check the glib string functions, they have all sorts of useful bits. A suffix checking function already exists.

```
gchar * str;

if (!g_str_has_suffix(str)) {
    return FALSE;
}
```

I'm kinda new at C, so I appologize if this isn't 100%... but it looks like a solid guard clause to me!

Answer (score 0):

My take on this:

```c
int string_has_suffix(const char* string, const char* suffix) {
    if (string && suffix) {
        if (strlen(string) >= strlen(suffix)) {
            const char* testLoc;
            testLoc = strrchr(string, suffix[0]);
            if (testLoc) {
                return (strcmp(suffix, testLoc) == 0);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not work if the first character in `suffix` is duplicated. example: `string_has_suffix("file.tar.gz", ".tar.gz")`

Answer (score 0):

I only wrote this because someone said something about "most optimized".

```
#include <stdint.h>

int_fast8_f EndsWithFoo(const char *str) {
    char c;
    union {
        uint32_t u;
        char s[4];
    } sfx = { .s = { '.','f','o','o'} },
      cur = { .u = 0 };
    c = *str;
    if (0 == c) { return 0; }
    cur.s[0] = c;
    c = *++str;
    if (0 == c) { return 0; }
    cur.s[1] = c;
    c = *++str;
    if (0 == c) { return 0; }
    cur.s[2] = c;
    c = *++str;
    if (0 == c) { return 0; }
    cur.s[3] = c;
    while (1) {
        c = *++str;
        if (0 == c) {
                if (cur.u == sfx.u)
                {
                        return 1;
                } else {
                        return 0;
                }
        }
        cur.s[0] = cur.s[1];
        cur.s[1] = cur.s[2];
        cur.s[2] = cur.s[3];
        cur.s[3] = c;
    }
}
```

No bytes are loaded from memory more than once (unless your target processor has hardly any registers).
The char/byte copies in the loop should be turned into a single logical shift by the compiler on any 32 bit or larger word target processor, but I coded it the way I did so that the C code didn't have to be endian aware.
The sfx (suffix) is turned into an integer constant by the compiler, and the equality suffix test is a single 32 bit integer equality test.
Each new byte has to be tested for 0.  While there are some bit twiddling ways to test for 0 as a byte within a word, they wouldn't safeguard against reading past the memory that we're supposed to have access to (assuming that str points to a properly terminated character string).

Comment: You should define `str` as a `const char *`. Also note that the above code does not work if `char` has more than 8 bits :)

Comment: @chqrlie: changed the parameter type to const, but this does rely on an 8bit char.

Comment: And now I’m thinking about this on an AVR, 8051, or other 8bit processor (possibly with some 16bit instructions).  The trade offs there get harder to weigh, but I might do a prefix of the suffix approach on those.  I’m also pondering optimization of the loads for architectures with memory busses wider than 8bits (again because I remember pondering it before).

Comment: Since you rely on 8-bit bytes, you should just define `sfx.s` as a `uint8_t s[4]`. The return type should be `int_fast8_t`. You can also simplify the return from the loop as `return (cur.u == sfx.u);`

Comment: @chqrlie: modification of the return from loop would not change anything except in a completely unoptimized case, and it aids in stepping through when debugging.  Changing it to (cur.u ^ sfx.u) might yield faster and/or smaller code, but occasionally people do write C does that relies on 1 for TRUE, and after the changing to int_fast8_t it doesn’t fit anymore anyway.  And if 8!=sizeof(char) then things get more complicated.  I’d probably add a compile trap to catch char size problems in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Or...

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

bool strendscmp(const char* haystack, const char* needle) {
    size_t len_str = strlen(haystack);
    size_t len_ending = strlen(needle);
    return len_str >= len_ending && strcmp(&haystack[(len_str - len_ending)], needle) == 0;
}

//SOME TESTS
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("%s\n", strendscmp("abc", "bc") ? "true" : "false"); //true
    printf("%s\n", strendscmp("abc", "d") ? "true" : "false"); //false
    printf("%s\n", strendscmp("abc", "") ? "true" : "false"); //true
    printf("%s\n", strendscmp("sumo", "omo") ? "true" : "false"); //false
    printf("%s\n", strendscmp("babbbba", "bbaabaab") ? "true" : "false"); //false
    printf("%s\n", strendscmp("dadaab", "bdadaab") ? "true" : "false"); //false
}
```

Comment: @chqrlie The last ```printf``` statement accounts for the issue of the ```needle``` being longer than the ```haystack```. Otherwise thanks for the corrections, I had made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would go with plinth's answer naturally, it is simple, elegant, and does not reinvent the wheel – just as it should be.

However, since this is a very basic problem, what I am missing here is a solution that is as bare-bones as it gets, so I would like to add a solution that is just that, it does not use any other function and uses only pointer-increments/decrements and comparisons:

```
#define SUFFIX_MATCH           0
#define SUFFIX_NO_MATCH        1
#define SUFFIX_INVALID_STR    -1
#define SUFFIX_INVALID_SUFFIX -2
#define SUFFIX_STR_TOO_SHORT   2

int str_endswith(char *str, char *suffix) {
/* find out, if a string ends with another string

  If str ends with suffix, return zero (to mimick how strcmp() from string.h
  works), otherwise return SUFFIX_NO_MATCH; return SUFFIX_INVALID_STR or
  SUFFIX_INVALID_SUFFIX if the respective parameter is NULL or an empty
  string, return SUFFIX_STR_TOO_SHORT if the suffix is longer than str.

  This function is case-sensitive and does not care about localisation etc.
*/
  if (str == NULL || *str == 0) return(SUFFIX_INVALID_STR);
  if (suffix == NULL || *suffix == 0) return(SUFFIX_INVALID_SUFFIX);

  char *p, *q;   // pointer, query-pointer (just arbitrary names)

  // set p to the last non-zero char of str
  p = str;
  while (*p++);
  --p;

  // move p forward as many characters as suffix has
  q = suffix;
  while (*q++ && p-- != str);
  if(p < str) {
    // if suffix is longer than str, there can be no success
    return(SUFFIX_STR_TOO_SHORT);
  }

  // compare what p points to with suffix, char by char
  q = suffix;
  while (*p == *q && *p && *q) {    // mind the \0
    ++p;
    ++q;
  }

  // if strings are equal, both pointers now point to \0
  if (*p == 0 && *q == 0) return(SUFFIX_MATCH);   // success!

  return(SUFFIX_NO_MATCH);   // or no success otherwise
}
```

*This is an edit,* I shamefully admit to have yanked the original code from one of my projects, simplified it too much, and did not test it thoroughly; this version here should be pretty much water-tight … and a good starting-point to build on should I want to do write a function for more fancy things which cannot be easily covered by standard library calls. Hope this helps!

And no, I did not use “const char” because I use functions like this on mutable strings, and this function returns zero *on success,* just like (as mentioned in the code) strcmp() does, which gives you the added benefit to, if so desired, be able to check *why* there was no match.

Comment: *no “const char” because I use functions like this on mutable strings*... This is not a problem: mutable strings can be passed as `const char *` arguments, the reverse is a constraint violation.

Comment: The code has undefined behavior if the suffix is longer than the string: `while (*q++ && p-- != str);` will leave `p` pointing before `str`, then `while (*p++ == *q++ && *p && *q);` will dereference this invalid pointer invoking undefined behavior.  Furthermore `str_endswith("ab"+1, "ab")` will return `1` instead of the expected `0`.

Comment: This implementation cannot handle empty strings: it has undefined behavior if either `str` or `suffix` is an empty string because it dereferences the byte after the null terminator.

Comment: Also the return value is counterintuitive: if `suffix` is a suffix of the string, you should return `1`  or `true`, not `0`.

Comment: To my dismay, I found out the original function always returned success even if str or suffix were strings with one character, I shamefully admit I had messed up the last while-statement. However @chqrlie about returning 1 on success … well, adapt the function to your liking if you use it, the important thing is, that this thing now works as intended in all possible cases.

Comment: I'm afraid I disagree: why should empty strings be considered invalid for this function? every string matches an empty suffix and the empty string only matches en empty suffix.

Comment: The comment `// move p forward as many characters as suffix has` is incorrect: you are moving `p` backwards and possibly before the beginning of the string, and in such a case, `if(p < str)` is not guaranteed to have defined behavior (and it would not on segmented architectures).

Comment: The test `while (*p == *q && *p && *q)` is redundant: `while (*p == *q && *p)` suffices.

Comment: Regarding the return value, `str_endswith` is named after a predicate, like `isdigit`, as such it is idiomatic in C to return 0 for false and a non zero value for true.

Comment: The comment `// set p to the last non-zero char of str` is misleading too: the code sets `p` to point to the null terminator.

Answer (score -1):

You can also generalize like this:

```
int endsWith(const char* text, const char* extn)
{
    int result = 1;
    int len = strlen(text);
    int exprLen = strlen(extn);
    int index = len-exprLen;
    int count = 0;

    if(len > exprLen)
    {
        for( ; count  < exprLen; ++count)
        {
            if(text[index + count] != extn[count])
            {
                result = 0;
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        result = 0;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your solution returns `0` if `text` and `extn` have the exact same contents, which seems incorrect. Also use `size_t` for index variables.

Answer (score -1):

General solution with one strlen(needle), strstr() and test for '\0':

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool endsWith(const char* haystack, const char* needle)
{
    bool rv = false;
    if (haystack && needle)
    {
        size_t needle_size = strlen(needle);
        if (needle_size == 0) return false;
        const char* act = haystack;
        while (NULL != (act = strstr(act, needle)))
        {   
            if (*(act + needle_size) == '\0')
            {   
                rv = true;
                break;
            }
            act += 1;
        }
    }

    return rv;
}

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char *a = "file1.gz";
    char *b = "1.gz";
    char *c = NULL;
    char *d = "1.gzabc";
    char *e = "1.gzabc1.gz";
    char *f = "";
    char *g = "rbrbr";
    char *h = "rbr";

    printf("endsWith:\n");
    printf("'%s' '%s' = %d\n",a,b,endsWith(a,b));
    printf("'%s' NULL = %d\n",a,endsWith(a,c));
    printf("'%s' '%s' = %d\n",d,b,endsWith(d,b));
    printf("'%s' '%s' = %d\n",e,b,endsWith(e,b));
    printf("'%s' '%s' = %d\n",e,f,endsWith(e,f));
    printf("'%s' '%s' = %d\n",g,h,endsWith(g,h));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This solution has an infinite loop for `needle = ""`. Furthermore it fails to match the suffix `"rbr"` of string `"rbrbr"`. To fix this problem, `act += needle_size;` should be changed to `act += 1;` making efficiency even worse in pathological cases.

Comment: @chqrlie: I added the changes, thx for the comments

Comment: When `needle` is an empty string, you should return `true`.

Comment: Logically that might be true, because `\0`, i.e. the empty string is the end of every C string, but can you give me an intuition where passing an empty string would be intentional and not the consequence of an error ?

Answer (score -1):

```
int strends(char* str, char* end){
    return strcmp(str + strlen(str) - strlen(end), end) == 0;
}
```

I found this is the simplest way to achieve the result.

Comment: assumes that end is shorter than str, probably should code defensively and check.

Answer (score -1):

On POSIX systems you can match the end of a string using glob patterns

```c
#include <fnmatch.h>

if (fnmatch("*.foo", my_string, 0))
  /* match */
```

Answer (score -2):

I would do it like this:

```
/**
  * Return 0 if the string haystack ends with the string needle
  * 
  * @param haystack the string to be analyzed
  * @param needle the suffix string
  * @return 0 if the string haystack ends with the string needle, 1 if not
*/
int strbcmp(const char *haystack, const char *needle) {
    int length;
    if (haystack && needle && strlen(haystack) >= (length = strlen(needle)) && strlen(strstr(haystack, needle)) == length) return 0;
   return 1;
}
```

The test program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int strbcmp(const char *haystack, const char *needle) {
    int length;
    if (haystack && needle && strlen(haystack) >= (length = strlen(needle)) && strlen(strstr(haystack,needle)) == length) return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main (int argc, char * argv[]){
    char *a = "file1.gz";
    char *b = "1.gz";
    char *c = NULL;
    char *d = "1.gzabc";

    printf("%s %s = %d\n",a,b,strbcmp(a,b));
    printf("%s %s = %d\n",a,c,strbcmp(a,c));
    printf("%s %s = %d\n",d,b,strbcmp(d,b));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does not even compile

Comment: Sorry for misspelling in the source code. It is fine now.

Comment: Following test does not work with your implementation:

    char *e = "1.gzabc1.gz";
    printf("%s %s = %d\n",e,b,strbcmp(e,b));

Comment: This code fails to match a trailing `needle` if it is present more than once in the `haystack` string.

Answer (score -3):

I'd suggest the best way of doing it is to reverse the string then compare the first n characters.

There's any number of examples of string reversing functions out there (even Joel cites it as a standard interview question) so just implement one of those then step though the reversed strings to compare.

EDIT in response to downvotes. OK yes, this approach does require additional CPU or memory to implement, but the questioner does not indicate any such constraints and he explicitly asked for an elegant solution.  Reversing the strings then comparing from the front is far more elegant than messing around finding the end of the strings and working backwards.  And it's a lot easier for the next programmer along to grasp and maintain too.

Comment: Yes, that would work, but it's either a memory allocation for a copy or a double reverse to undo the damage.

Comment: So what?  There's no indication that he's operating under under CPU or memory constrained circumstances and reversing the string to compare from the front is far more maintainable than messing around with finding the end-n position and hacking the logic from there.

Comment: You'd have to find the end of the string anyway to know how long it was so you'd know how to reverse it! It doesn't matter how you go about it, the problem involves the end of the string, so you'll have to find it one way or another.

Comment: of course, but if you reverse first the end of the string issue is effectively abstracted away into the reverse function, which is why it's a more elegant, maintainable and understandable solution

Comment: Except for the fact that it's horribly inefficient since you have to reverse the string twice, once to look at it and again to restore it, meaning read/write byte access for every byte in the string TWICE, just to look at the last four characters. Hardly understandable, hardly elegant at all.

Comment: No, because you put the reverse functionality into a function call so the function under discussion is simpler as that part is hidden.  As for inefficiency - well the difference is in microseconds, programmer time is more valuable

Comment: Given that there is no standard C89 or C99 function to reverse a string, you'd have to implement and test this function as well as the function just to check for .foo on the end. It would be simpler and easier and take less time to implement any of the supplied solutions for this problem than yours